# Modify text between HTML tags using PHP

Tags: php, text, replace

Let's say I have `index.php`:

```
 <p id="aid">Some text</p>
<?php
//SOME SCRIPT
?>
```

I want to do something like `document.getElementById('aid').innerHTML = "Changed TEXT"`, but in PHP. To replace text.
 Is this possible, using PHP? If yes, how?
Hope you understood me.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> document.getElementById('aid').innerHTML

is a Javascript code. It cannot be parsed by a PHP server.

What you could do is:

```
 <p id="aid"><?php
if(someCondition)
  echo "SOME SCRIPT";
else
  echo "Some text";
?></p>
```

Comment: @emailenin I am not talking to make the same thing in PHP. I know it is JS. I want something similiar or that can achieve the same results

Comment: @JakeaHacks Look at my PHP example.

Comment: I did a mistake. See it now. "Some script" is the script to achieve what I want

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Edit text between HTML tags, on specific conditions. (The "if, else" is something I can achieve myself

Comment: Also `echo` isn't the case. I want the PHP code to be separated from the html

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, whether it is possible of not, then no, it is not possible to do it in php.
There are different approaches, but for any text to change, using ONLY php, you will have to do reload the page, and update variable either using POST or GET method, or any other approach.

i'll show one example.

php code:

```
<?php
  $var = $_GET['var'];
?>
```

html would be:

```
<p><?php echo $var ?></p>
<a href="www.homeurl.com?var=new_value"> change var </a>
```

This is one way you can change the variable.

Comment: What about replacing the text?

Comment: Like, replacing a specific string with another

Comment: I have to get the text from another file (something I already did) and then replace some words. (So I need HTML and PHP separated)

Comment: OK, I did it myself. Just needed to put all the HTML in a variable and then str_replace

Comment: How does that separate your html and php file?
and what exactly were you trying to display if you don't mind telling

Comment: The HTML is taken from another page, so obviously it is saved in a variable. And I meant that I couldn't put PHP inside HTML, but I could put HTML inside PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify the DOM once the HTTP response has been sent to the client/browser. That's impossible with PHP.

But, your question was a little unclear. When I first read it I assumed you wanted to change the content of HTML **before** the response is sent back. This is possible:

```
<?php
    $aidValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
?>
<p id="aid"><?= $aidValues[array_rand($aidValues)]; ?></p>
```

The text node of the `p` element will contain a random value. Replace this with whatever logic you require.

Comment: I did it myself using str_replace() What I wanted was getting another HTML page and editing it

Comment: @JakeaHacks You didn't mention any of this in the question. Modify your question and I will edit the answer.

Comment: I said I did it myself

Comment: @JakeaHacks where?